# What does "$\mathbb{1}$" mean in this document?

Tags: notation, lebesgue-integral

I understand everything [in this document](http://www.math.umd.edu/~czaja/chap3.pdf) on the first page except the following:

> \begin{align}
>  \overline{\int_a^b}f&=\inf\left\{\int_a^b\psi:\psi\geqslant
>  f,\psi=\sum_{j=1}^nc_j\mathbb{1}_{\left(x_{j-1},x_j\right]}\right\}.
>  \end{align}

What does "$1_{\left(x_{j-1},x_j\right]}$" mean? Why is there a "$1$"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it is an indicator function, which is $1$ if $x \in (x_{j-1},x_j]$ and 0 otherwise.